# Excel Solver: define constraint to be zero or greater than

Tags: excel, solver

I'm creating a model to optimize purchase orders.

The amount to be ordered must be greater than 500 or equal to zero.

How do I define such a constraint in Solver?

I tried a binary constraint and I also tried several different formulas but nothing seems to work.

Basically I need to be able to express `OR` in `Solver`, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

- Add a binary variable: bin_var
- And a big_M (a big amount that orders will never reach)
- Then add two constraints

  - amount >= 500*bin_var
  - amount <= big_M*bin_var
- Resulting in:

  - if bin_var = 0 then amount = 0
  - if bin_var = 1 then amount >= 500

Answer (score 0):

use an integer decision with range 0 to 1 called it ProductSelected (say). then use a constraint as follows:

min amount * ProductSelected <= amount <= max amount * ProductSelected

when ProductDelected is zero, amount must be zero, when it is 1 amount must be in the range min to max.

Answer (score 0):

I tried kindoflost's suggestion and it did not work initially.

Later I tried using OpenSolver add-in and everything went ok.

So, if you cant make it work using regular Excel solver, give a chance to this add-in.